# How do I remove a row from wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

My current row in DataGrid1

```
DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)DataGridMain.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
```

But I want to delete it

```
DataGrid1.Rows.Remove(row);
```

But the last code do not work on WPF, how can i rewrite it?

> row.Delete(); does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you know index of your row "i" AND if you fill your DataGrid throug Items property (not using ItemsSource) - remove is simple:

```
        //if creating is:
        DataGridMain.Items.Add("one");
        DataGridMain.Items.Add("two");
        DataGridMain.Items.Add("three");
        //remove is:
        DataGridMain.Items.RemoveAt(1);
```

If you used DataGrid.ItemsSource property, so remove item by index from your ItemsSource object:

```
        //if creating is:
        var rows = new ObservableCollection<string> { "one", "two", "three"};
        DataGridMain.ItemsSource = rows;
        //remove is:
        rows.RemoveAt(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you should remove the row from your ItemsSource and row will be removed from your grid.

```
itemsSource.Remove(itemsSource[i])
```

where itemsSource is the itemsSource to your grid